# AAR integration error in kony studio 6.5

Tags: android, android-intent, aar, temenos-quantum

I have an android aar library which I want to integrate in a kony studio project. after contacting kony support I was able to integrate it and build the project correctly.

on run time when the aar is called, it calls for an activity (intent) inside the same aar. here I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/example/package/SecondActivity;
```

the way the activity is called is like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
intent.putExtra ()....;
startActivityForResult(intent, TASK2);    //TASK2 = 10;
```

i tried using import for the Second activity in the calling one but once i make the aar, android studio optimize the code by removing the import command as it is not needed.
is there a reason why the code now doesn't see the SecondActivity class? knowing that if I run the code on android studio it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ANT build system and not using gradle for dependency management . You will get these errors. First, migrate from ANT to gradle and specify your dependencies in the build.gradle.  I had the same problem when integrating an aar file .